# Activate ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 Cipher Suite in node js for tls connections

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, https, tls1.2

I want to implement a node js server that supports the cipher suite ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256, because the client supports only this algorithm. My Problem is that it seems that node js doesn't support this cipher. This is the configuration of my https Server:

```
const options = {
     key: fs.readFileSync('./cert/key.pem'),
     cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert/cert.crt'),
     requestCert: true,
     rejectUnauthorized: false,
     ciphers: 'ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256',
     secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_2_method',
     ecdhCurve:'prime256v1'
};
```

Do you have any ideas why the client can not connect to my server?

Comment: You would need an ECDSA certificate (probably you have an RSA certificate) for this. And I doubt that you really want to use `ECDH-...` and not `ECDHE-...` - the first is really uncommon and likely needs additional uncommon stuff in the certificate and probably in the SSL setup too.

Comment: I have an ECDSA certificate. The ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 cipher is working. My SSL setup is above. Do I have to change there something?

Comment: ECDH (not ECDHE) is tricky and I've seen several questions in the past which did not result in a usable answer. And it is also really strange from a client to require this. Maybe [Static DH/Static ECDH certificate using OpenSSL](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19452/static-dh-static-ecdh-certificate-using-openssl) and [OpenSSL generate different types of self signed certificate](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44251/openssl-generate-different-types-of-self-signed-certificate) will help.